# External Domain on Wordpress Multisite

Tags: plugins, customization, multisite, dns

I have a new wordpress multisite install. I want to point an external domain to a specific site on this install.  I'm using the [WP mu domain mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin. I'm hosting on Godaddy cpanel.

Things I've already done:

- Pointed an external domain(I own) DNS to this site
- Added sunrise.php to my root
- Setup WP multisite as a subdomain network
- Followed the instructions on the plugin page

No matter what I do though, my domain that I have pointed doesn't resolve. It doesn't show the WP install.

I simply want http://example1.com to show the WP install I have setup on something like http://test1.com. But keep the http://example1.com in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Any and all help is appreciated!